# Cannot assign to variable because it is borrowed

Tags: rust

I'm trying to re-assign a variable in a loop, but I keep running into `` cannot assign to `cur_node` because it is borrowed ``. Below I commented out the loop for simplicity, and it's the same problem. How do I handle this?

```
fn naive_largest_path(root: Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
    let mut cur_node = root.clone();
    let cur_node_borrowed = cur_node.borrow();

    // while cur_node_borrowed.has_children() {
        let lc = cur_node_borrowed.left_child.as_ref().unwrap();

        let left_child = cur_node_borrowed.left_child.as_ref().unwrap();
        let right_child = cur_node_borrowed.right_child.as_ref().unwrap();

        let left_val = left_child.borrow().value;
        let right_val = right_child.borrow().value;

        if left_val > right_val {
            cur_node = left_child.clone();
        } else {
            cur_node = right_child.clone();
        }
    // }
}

struct Node {
    value: i32,
    row_num: i32,
    position_in_row: i32,
    left_child: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
    right_child: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(val: i32, row: i32, pos_in_row: i32) -> Rc<RefCell<Node>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            value: val,
            row_num: row,
            position_in_row: pos_in_row,
            left_child: None,
            right_child: None,
        }))
    }

    fn has_children(&self) -> bool {
        self.left_child.is_some() || self.right_child.is_some()
    }
}
```

Comment: The only solution is to rewrite the code in a way that circumvents the issue. A few more details about what `Node` is and what you expect to get as the output of this function would be invaluable (edit them in the question).

Comment: This won't be the correct terminology (I'm a a rust novice at best), but it looks to me like your `cur_node_borrowed` is holding ownership of the the mutable borrow of `cur_node`.  So when you get down to the bottom, you're trying to mutate `cur_node` again while `cur_node_borrowed` is in scope.  Pushing `cur_node_borrowed` out of scope - thus losing the mutable borrow - should let you assign to cur_node again. (I just don't know the best way for you to do that, sorry). Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: @MatthieuM, I added my Node implementation. The goal is to return a vector of Nodes, based on the largest values of children. I removed it for brevity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the comments have said, you will need to restructure the code to make sure there is no borrow at the point where you want to assign to `cur_node`.  When dealing with `Rc` you can also often get away with a few extra `.clone()`, but that's cheating (and a little less efficient) :-).

Here's one way that compiles, taking advantage of Rust's [blocks-are-expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) feature:

```
fn naive_largest_path(root: Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {

    let mut cur_node = root.clone();

    while cur_node.borrow().has_children() {
        cur_node = {
            let cur_node_borrowed = cur_node.borrow();

            let lc = cur_node_borrowed.left_child.as_ref().unwrap();

            let left_child = cur_node_borrowed.left_child.as_ref().unwrap();
            let right_child = cur_node_borrowed.right_child.as_ref().unwrap();



            let left_val = left_child.borrow().value;
            let right_val = right_child.borrow().value;


            if left_val > right_val {
                left_child.clone()
            } else {
                right_child.clone()
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to assign it to the final if and not the whole block. That way it's a little clearer that that you changing a variable, which one, and where. Plus it will be less indented.